# Is it possible to find an analytical solution of a system of two 2nd order ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve two 2nd order ODEs of the general form:

$$\frac{d^2r}{dt^2}=f(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta})$$
$$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=g(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta})$$
where
$$\dot{r}=\frac{dr}{dt},\quad \dot{\theta}=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$$
Although I can solve the two equations numerically for any given expression of the functions $f(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta})$ and $g(r,\theta,\dot{r},\dot{\theta})$, I am interested to know whether a general analytical solution can be obtained for the problem. I am not aware of any such method that can be used to find analytical solution for systems of ODEs.

Comment: An overwhelming majority of scalar DE of first order does not have a symbolic or analytical solution, why would you expect different if you increase the difficulty to a two-dimensional second order system?

Answer (score 5):

There are existence result that assures you that such solution exists, and it is unique provided initial data. [Here](https://ajpancollantes.github.io/%E2%99%BE%EF%B8%8F%20CONCEPTS/DEs/system%20of%20first%20order%20ODEs.md.html) you can find some personal notes about it. This is the reason that you always find numerical approximations.

On the other hand, I think that what you mean is "analytical expression" of the solutions, or [closed form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression). In general, the answer is NO. This is an important field of research. An important reference for this topic is [this](https://books.google.es/books?hl=es&lr=&id=nFSJn7dIYysC&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=stephani+differential+equations&ots=UCqloEf9yl&sig=1Q2Qsuo4h_qB8skXPh-M_nhnUDc). Also, look for "integrable systems".